# .htaccess rule - check if the request is for a folder or file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to check the requested URL, and serve different options depending on whether the request is for a file or a directory.

My URLs would look like:

- `http://www.example.com/Services/Service-1` (directory, serve `/pages/Services/Service1/index.php`)
- `http://www.example.com/Services/Service-1/Feature-1/Sub-Feature` (an actual file, serve `/pages/Services/Service-1/Feature-1/Sub-Feature.php`)

Because of my lack of understanding of .htaccess (would this need a RewriteCondition?), I am currently stuck enumerating out each and every folder of my directory structure as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^Services/Service-1/(.*)$ /pages/Services/Service-1/$1.php
RewriteRule ^Services/Service-1 /pages/Services/Service-1/index.php

RewriteRule ^Services/Service-2/(.*)$ /pages/Services/Service-2/$1.php
RewriteRule ^Services/Service-2 /pages/Services/Service-2/index.php

RewriteRule ^Services/(.*)$ /pages/Services/$1.php
RewriteRule ^Services /pages/Services/index.php

RewriteRule ^Testimonials/(.*)$ /pages/Testimonials/$1.php
RewriteRule ^Testimonials /pages/Testimonials/index.php
```

Needless to say, this is a real pain - any time I add folders of content, I have to mess with .htaccess.

I know there must be a better way, but my google and stackoverflow searches haven't turned up anything that works when I try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you guessed it right, a rewriteCond can be used to verify if the requested uri is a file or a directory:

```
# f for a file, d for a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

you .htaccess would be:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine ON    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.+) /$1/index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.+) /$1.php [QSA,L]
```

**EDIT**:
if your files reside in the page sub directory , you have to use the following code:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine ON    

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1 -d
RewriteRule (.+) /pages/$1/index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.+) /pages/$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks - when I try this, I get 404 errors for the requested URL. It seems like this would just check for (and rewrite URLs in) the root directory. Would this work for nested directories?

Comment: The funny thing is, for this to work you'll have to _disable_ the `MultiViews` option I gave in my answer, so add `Options -MultiViews` at the top of this and it'll work. On a side note: every time I forget to add `QSA` to the flags it comes back to bite me, so I've taken to always include it like `[L,QSA]` (the `NC` here is not necessary in this particular case as there are no characters in the pattern).

Comment: @Wrikken , you're right about flags :), regarding `MultiViews `, isn't disabled by default?

Comment: @Amine: well, it's not enabled unless expicitly done so, but I know for a fact Debian & 'buntu flavors tend to have it enabled for their starting default host, and as most people just copy & alter that config they tend to have `Options MultiViews`  somewhere in there (the OP could also simply remove it there). Actually, I'm quite certain the OP has it enabled, otherwise your answer would simply work as given ;)

Comment: since my content is served from the /pages directory, would I need it to be `RewriteRule (.+) /pages/$1/index.php [QSA,L]` ? I have tried it both ways with no success

Comment: is pages a subdirectory of the website root folder? where is your .htaccess located?

Comment: Yes, /pages is a subdirectory of my website root folder. .htaccess is in the website root

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest if mod negotiation is enabled (it usually is):

```
Options MultiViews
MultiviewsMatch Any
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Won't force the .php though, if you have somefile.html as well as somefile.php the .html file is usually selected.

Comment: directory indexes are already specified in httpd.conf, so that part is not an issue. The real issue is having it decide whether to server file.php or file/index.php

Comment: Ah, check, point taken. See my comment @ Amine's answer to make that one work.